# MS SQL Server 2008 Encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encoding, character-encoding

I have table in database with Lithuanian_100_CI_AS collation. Some rows has text fields with text, which contains random symbols instead of Lithuanian ones. Is it possible to change the encoding, that i would see the letters i need? Changing collation does totally nothing.

Comment: Probably not. If you inserted it incorrectly the data will already be lost. I assume the default collation of the DB is something other than Lithuanian? In which case use the `N` prefix when inserting string literals to avoid it being coerced into the code page of your database's default collation.

Comment: text or ntext? (which shouldn't be used anyway)

Comment: For all text fields in these tables i use NVARCHAR(256), because these are not very long strings. Database collation is Lithuanian_100_CI_AS. The problem is that data was imported from CSV which had wrong encoding. I am not able to reimport data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got the data like this (manipulated) then you can not realy save it by changing the collation, but if you set the right collation this could help you to get the data written in a right way to your database (more relevant for the future)

Answer (score 0):

No, the data is random.

You need to

- use nvarchar to store this data correctly
- ensure the client is using nvarchar for parameters
- ensure all string constants have N in front (example: `N'foobar'`)

The collation is not encoding: it only determins how strings and compared/sported, but determines the code page for non-unicode (unicode = nvarchar) columns

Note, the [data types "text" and "ntext" are deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) in SQL Server. Use the max types